# Cannot install Oracle 12c on Windows 8.1 - Error in Process ... perl.exe

Tags: oracle, installation, windows-8.1, oracle12c

When installing Oracle 12c personal edition on a freshly minted Windows8.1 box I get the following error:

```
Title: Database Configuration ...
Error in Process:
C:\app\<username>\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\perl\bin\perl.exe
```

Clicking ok and skipping gives the following error

```
[INS-20802] Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed.
Details: The plug-in failed in its perform method ...
```

Trying lots of things but still come up with same error. Googling shows some users with the same error, but all end in dead-ends without a solution.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with Oracle Database 12c on a fresh Windows 8.1.
For me the solutions was deactivating a preinstalled McAfee.
I used the Windows-builtin-User during the Oracle-Database Installation.

Answer (score 1):

Think this may be it. The new Windows user for the account was `oracle-user`. When I tried this with a username `OracleUser` the installation worked.

I also switched off the AntiVirus - not sure which fixed the problem

A colleague pointed me to [this blog](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2013/07/26/oracle-12c-on-windows-7/) which gave a little more info.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the Anti-virus program most probably McAfee. If you want complete instructions check this out - [It is an explanation of the step by step installation process specifically on windows 8.1 and the perl.exe error](http://softechstuff.blogspot.in/2015/08/oracle-database-12cinstallation.html)